# i want to get a table values with a row number this is giving syntax error.can any one help me?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
 SELECT @ihotelID= [hotelID] , @ihotelCode = [hotelCode], @iroomTypeCode = [roomTypeCode] ,@dcratePerNight=[ratePerNight],
           @iroomid =[roomid],@inoOfRooms =[noOFRooms],@Datefrom=toDate,@sstatus=status,@specialday='No',
          @dcb2BPercentage=[b2BPercentage],@dcb2CPercentage=[b2CPercentage],@sadditionalBenefits=[imgBenefits]  
FROM (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY hotelID) AS 'RowNo' FROM RoomDetails1 t1)
```

Comment: how about formatting your query nicely? Plus, what is the (exact) error?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to SELECT fields that aren't being returned by your subquery (which only returns RowNo).

Try e.g.:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY hotelID) AS 'RowNo', [hotelID] ,[hotelCode],........
FROM RoomDetails1 t1
```

For demo, I've removed the assignments for field values into variables - just to make it clear what the change was

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will make the necessary changes